# obtener el id de mi select para guardarlo en mi base de datos

Tags: php, javascript

muy buenas 
estoy trabajando en un pagina web los select estan llenos con datos que estan en mi base, lo que necesito es obtener el id que tiene cada opcion en el select para registrar solo el id ya que las tablas estan relacionadas
ejemplo 
el id 1=soltero no quiero registrar la palabra soltero sino solo el numero 1 por eso solo quiero obtener el id 
este es mi codigo de la pagina web

```
    <title>HTML Education Template</title>

    <!-- Google font -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:700%7CMontserrat:400,600" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css"/>

    <!-- Font Awesome Icon -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.min.css">

    <!-- Custom stlylesheet -->
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

</head>
<body>

    <!-- Header -->
    <header id="header">
        <div class="container">

            <div class="navbar-header">
                <!-- Logo -->
                <div class="navbar-brand">
                    <a class="logo" href="index.html">
                        <img src="./img/levox2.png" alt="logo">
                    </a>
                </div>
                <!-- /Logo -->

                <!-- Mobile toggle -->
                <button class="navbar-toggle">
                    <span></span>
                </button>
                <!-- /Mobile toggle -->
            </div>

            <!-- Navigation -->
            <nav id="nav">
                <ul class="main-menu nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a href="empleado.html">empleado</a></li>
                    <li><a href="PROVEEDORES.html">proveedor</a></li>
                    <li><a href="camiones.html">camiones</a></li>
                    <li><a href="accidentes.html">accidentes</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
            <!-- /Navigation -->

        </div>
    </header>
    <!-- /Header -->

        <div id="home" class="hero-area-empleado">

        <!-- Backgound Image -->
        <div class="bg-image bg-parallax overlay" style="background-image:url(./img/home-background.jpg)"></div>
        <!-- /Backgound Image -->
                    <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-12">

                    <form class="form3" action="base/registrar_empleado.php"  method="post" >
                      <h1 class="PROVEEDORES">REGISTRO DE EMPLEADO</h1>
                      <fieldset class="EMPLEADO">
                         <input type="text" name="cedula" placeholder="CEDULA" class="cedula">
                         <input type="text" name="nombre" placeholder="NOMBRE" class="nombre">
                         <label>fecha de ingreso</label>
                         <input type="date" name="fecha_ingreso" class="fecha">
                         <input type="text" name="domicilio" placeholder="DOMICILIO" class="nombre">
                         <input type="text" name="telefono" placeholder="TELEFONO" class="telefono">
                         <input type="text" name="celular" placeholder="CELULAR" class="telefono">
                         <input type="email" name="correo" placeholder="CORREO" class="nombre">   
                        <label>Estado civil:</label> 
                        <select width="100px" name="estado_civil">
                        <option value="" width="100px">Seleccione:</option>
                          <?php
                      $query = $mysqli -> query ("SELECT * FROM estado_civil");
                      while ($valores = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
                          echo '<option value="'.$valores[ec_id].'">'.$valores[ec_nombre].'</option>';
                      }
                      ?>
                        </select>

                        <label>tipo empleado:</label>


                        <select width="100px" name="tipo_empleado">
                        <option value="" width="100px">Seleccione:</option>
                          <?php
                      $query = $mysqli -> query ("SELECT * FROM tipo_empleado");
                      while ($valores = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
                          echo '<option value="'.$valores[tpem_id].'">'.$valores[tpem_nombre].'</option>';
                      }
                      ?>
                        </select> 

                          <label>datos licencia</label>

                          <label>tipo de licencia:</label>
                        <select width="100px" name="tipo_licencia">
                        <option value="" width="100px">Seleccione:</option>
                          <?php
                      $query = $mysqli -> query ("SELECT * FROM tipo_licencia");
                      while ($valores = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
                          echo '<option value="'.$valores[tlc_id].'">'.$valores[tlc_nombre].'</option>';
                      }
                      ?>
                        </select>

                         <label>licencia expedicion</label>
                         <input type="date" name="fecha_caducida" class="fecha">
                         <label>caducida de licencia</label>
                         <input type="date" name="fecha_caducida" class="fecha">
                         <input type="submit" value="Ingresar" >
                        </fieldset>

                    </form>         

                    </div>


                </div>




    <!-- /Hero-area -->

    <footer id="footer" class="section">

        <!-- container -->
        <div class="container">

            <!-- row -->
            <div class="row">

                <!-- footer logo -->
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="footer-logo">
                        <a class="logo" href="index.html">
                            <img src="./img/logo.png" alt="logo">
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>


            <!-- row -->
            <div id="bottom-footer" class="row">

              <ul class="footer-social">
                <li><a href="#" class="facebook"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="twitter"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="google-plus"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="instagram"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="youtube"><i class="fa fa-youtube"></i></a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="linkedin"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- row -->


        </div>
        <!-- /container -->

    </footer>
    <!-- /Footer -->



    <!-- jQuery Plugins -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>


</body>
```

Comment: ¿Entonces lo que quieres básicamente es obtener el id del `option` seleccionado del `select` por Javascript? ¿O por alguna razón el de todos los `option`s?

Comment: Así es quiero obtener el ID de los 3 option seleccionado que tengo

Answer (score 1):

De acuerdo a lo que me comentas en los comentarios, necesitas obtener los `id`s de los `option`s seleccionados de los tres `select`s que tienes.
Para hacer esto y sin usar `jQuery`ni nada externo, puedes usar la función `seleccionar` que obtiene el valor buscando el elemento por su `name`.

```js
function seleccionar() {
  let estado_civil = document.getElementsByName("estado_civil")[0].value;
  let tipo_empleado = document.getElementsByName("tipo_empleado")[0].value;
  let tipo_licencia = document.getElementsByName("tipo_licencia")[0].value;
  return {estado_civil, tipo_empleado, tipo_licencia};
}

let values = seleccionar();
console.log(values);
```

```html
<select width="100px" name="estado_civil">
  <option value="1" selected>Value1</option>
  <option value="2">Value2</option>
  <option value="3">Value3</option>
</select>
<select width="100px" name="tipo_empleado">
  <option value="1">Value1</option>
  <option value="2">Value2</option>
  <option value="3" selected>Value3</option>
</select>
<select width="100px" name="tipo_licencia">
  <option value="1">Value1</option>
  <option value="2" selected>Value2</option>
  <option value="3">Value3</option>
</select>
```